I can't run my Flutter app on iOS Simulator and subsequently can't get a successful build in XCode for deployment
Getting this error while trying to run on iOS Simulator:
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
--- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:F3F94F7F-DFC2-4EDA-9F79-23EC8DFCB2A8, OS:16.0, name:11 max }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:F3F94F7F-DFC2-4EDA-9F79-23EC8DFCB2A8, OS:16.0, name:11 max }
** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
Writing result bundle at path:
/var/folders/x2/cmkskh752blb__xzhdqrh2tm0000gn/T/flutter_tools.urJG7L/flutter_ios_build_temp_diraeO3Mp/temporary_xcresult_bundle
/Users/kawikakawikamac/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/url_launcher_ios-6.3.0/ios/url_launcher_ios/Sources/url_launcher_ios/Launcher.swift:22:1: error: type 'UIApplication' does not conform to protocol 'Launcher'
extension UIApplication: Launcher {}
^
UIKit.UIApplication:24:15: note: candidate has non-matching type '(URL, [UIApplication.OpenExternalURLOptionsKey : Any], (@MainActor @Sendable (Bool) -> Void)?) -> Void'
    open func open(_ url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenExternalURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:], completionHandler completion: (@MainActor @Sendable (Bool) -> Void)? = nil)
              ^
/Users/kawikakawikamac/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/url_launcher_ios-6.3.0/ios/url_launcher_ios/Sources/url_launcher_ios/Launcher.swift:22:1: note: add stubs for conformance
extension UIApplication: Launcher {}
^
Command SwiftEmitModule failed with a nonzero exit code

I tried updating the url_launcher package, re-installing the pods file, tried flutter clean and flutter pub get
I updated XCode to version 16.1 recently I suspect that might've caused the issue

Check your package version and update lates version for your package's and run the pod installer or not work try downgrade your XCODE 15 (https://xcodereleases.com/).
